# SQL Server - Combine string to integer where integer can have a variable number of leading zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report in SQL Server Report Builder which brings back the profession acronym (string) and registration number (integer) for each professional in a separate SQL database.

The registration number can be 5 or more digits long, and may start with one or more zeros. For example:

```
Profession  Registration #
AB          00162
PH          02272
SA          13925
SA          026025
DA          1025927
```

I'm trying to put the profession acronym and registration number together into a registration ID, because I need to compare this with the registration ID from another (non SQL) database.

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
Registration ID
AB00162
PH02272
SA13925
SA026025
DA1025927
```

I've tried converting the integers to strings using the following in my query:

```
REGISTRY.PROFESSION + right('00000' + cast(REGISTRY.REGISTRATION_NO as varchar(8)), 5) as Full_Reg_Number
```

However, with the above the integers that are more than 5 digits long get cut off, and if I increase `'00000'` to, say, `'0000000'` and the number `'5'` to `'7'` in the above, the integers that only have 5 digits are padded with extra leading zeros.

I do not have permission to change the formatting of the integers in either database.

Comment: Don't post images.  Format the the text using the brackets {}

Comment: Integers aren't stored with leading zeroes.  To be stored like that, then the field is NOT of integer type in the first place.  Simply do `Registry.profession + registry.registration_no`.

Comment: Thank you, @pwilcox but unfortunately I get the following error in this case: "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric".

Comment: @SeanLange I'm afraid that's how the numbers are in the other database, hence my problem with the length when concatenating.

Comment: Well...as already stated since you have leading zeros already these are not integers. Just add them together.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming directly due to the concatenation?  Maybe it's down the line, such as if you're using Full_Reg_Number in a where statement or other comparison that expects a comparison to an integer, and instead is getting varchar?  After all, you called it 'Full_Reg_Number' even though it's not a number.

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti, apologies, first time posting and the tables took a bit to show up as tables.

Comment: `Registry.profession + registry.registration_no` on it's own isn't going to generate that error your have (based on the sample data), which means something else is causing the error or your sample data isn't representative of your actual data.

Comment: @Cactus, what is the output of the information_schema query I provided in my answer?

Comment: @pwilcox I get decimal. Gordon Linoff's solution below works for me. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I've learnt a lot of useful things.

Answer (score 1):

Integers aren't stored with leading zeroes. To be stored like that, then the field is NOT of integer type in the first place. Simply do:

```
Registry.profession + registry.registration_no
```

You can confirm that the stored type is not an integer as follows:

```
select    data_type
from      information_schema.columns
where     table_name = 'registry'
and       column_name = 'registration_no'
```

If you're getting a type conversion error as you mention in your comments, then most likely the error is not coming due to this concatenation.  It's probably down the line, such as if you're using 'Full_Reg_Number' in a 'where' statement or other comparison that expects a comparison to an integer, and instead is getting a varchar.  After all, you called the column 'Full_Reg_Number' even though it's not a number.

Comment: Thank you, @pwilcox, I've learnt something new and will make sure I use it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problems, I suspect those really are integers.  You've just shown them with leading zeros in the question.

A simple solution is to use `case`:

```
(REGISTRY.PROFESSION +
 CASE WHEN REGISTRY.REGISTRATION_NO < 10000 THEN right('00000' + cast(REGISTRY.REGISTRATION_NO as varchar(8)), 5) 
      ELSE REGISTRY.REGISTRATION_NO
 END
) as Full_Reg_Number
```

An even simpler method uses `FORMAT()`:

```
(REGISTRY.PROFESSION + FORMAT(REGISTRY.REGISTRATION_NO, '00000')
) as Full_Reg_Number
```

Comment: Many thanks, @GordonLinoff. The FORMAT solution worked a treat.